# | a + b | = | a | + | b |

Tags: calculus

Working through Keisler's Elementary Calculus.  Section 1.2 exercise 26 asks the reader to show that the subject of this post holds true when `a` and `b` have the same sign, and LHS < RHS when they do not.

I'm not sure where to begin with this, also the solutions in the appendix are for odd numbered exercises only. Is there a resource for fully worked solutions for this book?

Comment: You know the definition for absolute value, right? If so, consider when a, b are positive. Then proceed when they are negative.

Comment: if $a,b > 0$ you know $|a| = a $ and $|b| =b$. Also, $a+b > 0 $, so... if both are negative, then $|a| = -a $ and $|b| = -b  $, and $a+b < 0$, so ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both sides are by definition non-negative, squaring is an equivalence transformation that in addition preserves the order.

So let's square the equation:
$$|a+b|^2 = (|a|+|b|)^2$$
Since you are speaking about "the same sign" I assume $a$ and $b$ are assumed to be real numbers (as for complex numbers "sign" doesn't make sense), therefore under the square we can drop the absolute value bars (for real numbers we have $|x|^2 = x^2$):
$$(a+b)^2 = (|a|+|b|)^2$$
Now let's use the binomial formula, and on the right hand side again drop absolute value bars under squares:
$$a^2 + 2 a b + b^2 = a^2 + 2 |a|\,|b| + b^2$$
Now we see that on both sides we can subtract $a^2 + b^2$:
$$2 a b = 2 |a|\,|b|$$
Let's divide both sides by two and use the fact that $|a|\,|b| = |ab|$, and we obtain:
$$ab = |ab|$$
Clearly, this equation is fulfilled exactly if $ab$ is positive, that is, if $a$ and $b$ have the same sign. Also, if $ab$ is negative, then obviously it's less than $|ab|$ because a negative number is always less than a positive number.

Since all operations we did were order-preserving equivalence transformations, the same then holds for the original equation.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : when you encounter horrible things like absolute values or integer parts, try to give them a value according to some hypothesis.

For example here : distinguish four cases :

- $a$ and $b$ positive : the equation becomes $a+b=a+b$
- $a$ and $b$ negative : the equation becomes $-(a+b)=-a-b$
- $a$ positive, $b$ negative, $a+b$ positive : the equation becomes $a+b<a-b$
- $a$ positive, $b$ negative, $a+b$ negative : the equation becomes $-(a+b) < a-b$.

The cases $a$ negative and $b$ positive are symmetrical.

Answer (score 0):

In general, $|a + b| \le |a| + |b|$.

If $a, b$ have opposite signs, suppose $a > 0$ and $b < 0$. Also suppose $|a + b| = |a| + |b|$ therefore $|a + b| = a -b$ which leads to $a + b = a - b$ or $-a -b = a -b$ impossible.